# How many ways can 12 identical flowers be distributed to 3 distinct vases such that at most 1 vase can have no flower?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This is the answer from the book.
$$
    {11 \choose 2}+11 \times 3=88
$$

Is the book answer correct? If so, can someone explain?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?  [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is relevant here.

Comment: The stated answer is obtained by adding the number of distributions in which no vase is left empty and the number of distributions in which exactly one vase is left empty.  Does that help?

Comment: The OP should post what is his/her thoughts about this problem , then we may help you in this .

Comment: Yes the book's answer is correct.  @AirMike perhaps you got concerned since you didn't see $12$ in the answer anywhere... but note that subtractions have already been completed.  It isn't as simplified if we were to have written it as $\binom{12-1}{3-1}+\binom{12-1}{2-1}\times 3$

Comment: @JMoravitz yes that’s make sense, I realised that later, but thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: Funny that "stars and bars" approach can also give you a simpler answer ${14 \choose 2}-3=88$  (number of ways to put flowers into the cases no matter how many are empty, minus 3 ways of putting all flowers into one vase).

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.I get it now.